# Java Return Code not being properly recorded with C++ system() call

Tags: java, c++

Java code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main ( String[] args ) {   
         System.exit ( 4 );
    }
}
```

C++ code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {
    int result = system ( "java Test" );
    printf ( "Result: %d", result ); 
}
```

Running this C++ program outputs

```
"Result: 1024"
```

If I run the java program directly, and check the value of the return status using bash's $? variable, I get 4:

```
> java Test
> echo $?
4
```

So it seems I'm misunderstanding or misusing the System call.

How do I get this return value of "4" from system() call, rather than "1024", and where is "1024" coming from?

Thank you!

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/

Comment: From your link: "If command is not a null pointer, the value returned depends on the system and library implementations, but it is generally expected to be the status code returned by the called command, if supported." 

That's what I read which led me to expect the behavior I'm expecting. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: _depends on the system and library implementations_ Check your library implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `WEXITSTATUS` on the result of the `system` call to get the exit status.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {
    int result = system ( "java Test" );
    printf ( "Result: %d", WEXITSTATUS( result ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the correct results. The return value from system() is not the exit code from the child process, but a status code that includes the exit code, and several other flags.

For more information see the system() man page, which refers you to the waitpid() man page that describes the macros that can be used to process the return value from system().